# I need folder permissions set to drwxrwxrwt instead of drwsrwsrwx

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-10.10

I just need permissions set to `drwxrwxrwt` instead of the current `drwsrwsrwx` .

When I transfer files from filezilla to my Ubuntu server in the www folder, it doesn't give them the 755 permission. How can I fix this?  (This started happening only recently.)

Comment: Maybe your system administrator did that for a reason? I made this exact change to my users' web folders yesterday. Has it been bringing you trouble?

Comment: @Ekevoo It sounds like he is the system administrator.

Comment: @jgbelacqua I Skype regularly with my users and they have had the habit of asking me things directly when they want to understand something about our server. I hope this isn't changing. :(

Answer (score 3):

If you can move the data into the directory, just create a new one.

```
mkdir dir
chmod 1777 dir
```

If you need over an existing directory without moving data, check the man page:

> chmod preserves a directory's
>   set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits 
>   unless you  explicitly  specify
>   otherwise.  You can set or clear the
>   bits with symbolic modes like u+s and
>   g-s, and you can set (but  not  clear)
>   the bits with a numeric mode.

Greetings

Comment: Basically this means you should do `chmod ug-s DIRECTORY`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the umask for the directory or for the user you are using.

Google for "linux directory umask". In this case you want a umask of 022.  That will block write permission for group and other.

Cheers.

Comment: i just need this permission drwxrwxrwt instead of the current drwsrwsrwx. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible simply with `sudo chmod 1777 /path/to/www` .